# Not able to update Entity framework Core relationship from Masstransit Saga Event

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, masstransit, automatonymous

I am unable to update the entity relationship in my saga instance event.

I am able to create One-to-One row for an entry however while I come back to IssueLocation state again it is not detecting row is already exist and thorwing error

here is my code https://github.com/jaisopenoffice/IssueRequestStateMachine/tree/master

I need to update IssueLocation instead of adding new record(at IssueTypeAccepted event). First time it is working but when I come back to the same state again that's where it is trying to create new record. Is there a right way to do it?

Comment: How are the other events CorrelationId being initialized, which in the case of a saga, much match the existing saga instance? You may need to correlate on some other identifier that your event producers know.

Comment: Yes, I am using CorrelationId to map between events and it is expecting to match existing saga instance.

While loading the object-graph it is bringing child objects as null. For example, in Step 3[IssueDetails step] the IssueLocation object is showing as null which I already set at Step 2

Comment: Try to make it work without MassTransit - add IssueLocation, save changes, read it again. I bet you get null there too. Fix your mappings and it will work as saga too. This is just EntityFramework.

Comment: I was able to make it work outside of MT by only using "include" in EF which is not possible to move my code to MT

Comment: Have you made any samples of EF & MT with object relationships in its Saga State Machine Instance? It will be easier to figure out that way

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you've got to work on your mappings but I know this is an old question but one I had trouble finding an answer to. In my Program.cs I add a custom .include statement. It loads it perfectly, and updates it perfectly (previously it only updated if I .saga.Person = .message.Person and that only persisted if I was transitioning to another state) so hopefully this helps someone else.

```
x.AddSagaStateMachine<PersonStateMachine, PersonState>() 
.EntityFrameworkRepository(r =>
{
    r.ExistingDbContext<PersonSagaDbContext>();
    r.UseSqlServer();
    r.CustomizeQuery(query =>
    {
        return query.Include(s => s.Person);
    });
});
```